# Asp.net MVC Domain and sub domain creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC  and I'm working on a project that provide to visitor register our shop my site with a sub-domain of my company website, for example http://www.shopify.com/ is website. then after registration this provide a domain to access our website to our visitor like http://myksb.myshopify.com/ or www.myksb.shopify.com

Here shopify.com is main website domain name, and myksb is customer shop name.

Now,I want to create a myksb.com dynamically.

Finally we can register our shop on this website with desired subdomain.

Comment: this can only be done in your DNS Provider settings page. it's non-aspnet related topic.

Answer (score 0):

See whether below link can help you

http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_asp_net/3194877.htm